# Space consumption with SVN tags

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have one svn branch, say branches/Branch1 and I am tagging the source to tags/tag1. As per my understanding SVN will not copy all the source from branches to tags, but it will create a link so that for tags it will not consume space.

I have noticed that even if I delete Branch1, tag1 is existing. Curious to know in this case where the sources under tag1 will be saved and whether it will consume space in my server. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete branch, you delete it only in "now" state of repository, not in history (which is immutable and always accessible)

Because for Tag1 it's source (**full** source) is known (Branch1@REV), it can be extracted from repo-history when and as it needed

Answer (score 1):

> SVN will not copy all the source from branches to tags, but it will create a link so that for tags it will not consume space.

It's not exactly a "link" in the same sense as symlink on your filesystem. When you create the copy, you're creating a pointer in the repository that basically says "to find tags/tag1, go to revision X and find branches/Branch1".

Because things are never truly deleted from a Subversion repository (only removed from view at the `HEAD` revision), you can always go back to older revisions and see things as they existed in the past.